# What happens in the memory and does a new process always open a new JVM in Java?

Tags: java, process, jvm, stack, heap-memory

1. What happens in Java when we start a new process using `ProccessBuilder.start()` or `RunTime.getRunTime.exec()`?

Will it open a new JVM with a new stack & heap of the new process?
Does a new JVM is opened when we create and run a new process?

Comment: Unless the new process that you are starting is the JVM, I don't see why you would think a new JVM would be opened?

Comment: Please read the Javadoc for the classes you mentioned, run some small experiments, and ask any questions you are left with.

Comment: Why not simply looking into Task Manager / Activity Monitor / top / htop? There you can see how many java processes are running and how much memory they consume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens in Java when we start a new process using ProccessBuilder.start() or RunTime.getRunTime.exec()?

From [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) *"Starting an operating system process is highly system-dependent."*

> Will it open a new JVM with a new stack & heap of the new process? Does a new JVM is opened when we create and run a new process?

No, simply a new [**system process**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) will be created (similar to start a new process using the system shell like `$ program` or `C:\> program.exe`).

E.g. running:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("sleep", "10").start();
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("End");
```

produce a new system process (independent of the JVM runtime)

```
$ ps -AF | grep sleep
josejuan   80777   80751  0  2135   732   3 08:36 tty1     00:00:00 sleep 10
```

even if you do not wait, the JVM ends their execution but the process is still running

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command("sleep", "10").start();
System.out.println("End");
```

with output

```
End
```

but system process

```
[josejuan@plata ~]$ ps -AF | grep sleep
josejuan   80866       1  0  2135   684   1 08:37 tty1     00:00:00 sleep 10
```

Comment: so 2 different processes will use the same JVM? What exactly `simply a new system process will be created ` means?

Comment: Since the Java process is already running, _"a new process"_ means that a new system process will be created with the command you have specified. Bold in _"system process"_ is important. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)

Comment: @user16320675 I still can't get it.
my simple question is : Does `(new ProcessBuilder).start("my2ndprogram.o")` will open a new JVM along with the process?